# Why has my Mac been running fsck_hfs for two days now?

Tags: macos, filesystems, time-machine, hfs, fsck

I first noticed that `fsck_hfs` was running, taking up 50-75% of a CPU, yesterday. It continues to run today.

Running `ps -ax` shows that it is doing `/sbin/fsck_hfs -f -n -x -E /dev/disk3`. Only problem: I don’t think I have a `/dev/disk3`.

1. Why is it running?
2. Will it ever finish?

- Can I `kill` it?

1. What is `/dev/disk3`? Could it be my Time Machine volume, which is not mounted at the moment?

**System Info:** MacBook Pro (2008). It has two disks installed—the internal disk (`/dev/disk1`) and a PC Card SSD (`/dev/disk0`, surprisingly). It connects to a remote Time Machine volume attached to an Airport Extreme base station.

Comment: another datapoint; my 10.13.5 laptop just spent two hours "verifying" a backup on a NAS drive, apparently stuck at 84%.  Majority of the CPU time was going to `fsck_hfs` (similar command line to the OP) with basically zero network traffic (~5 packets per second) and I think disk IO Ops/s were low as well but I wasn't checking that as much.  No apparent change in progress was reported in the GUI (that I noticed) and then it just completed successfully.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. It was probably running from when your Time Machine volume was mounted.
2. If the volume isn't present anymore, I doubt it.

   - I'm sure you can `sudo killall fsck_hfs`; it wouldn't hurt anything. (Have you tried restarting?)
3. It probably is.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You were right. Moments after `kill`ing it, Time Machine popped up saying it was unable to verify my backup. It probably became confused last night when I closed my MacBook and took it home. Crazy that it will try to verify a ~750 GB disk image over Wi-Fi! I would have to leave my computer turned on and at the office for several days for it to complete…

Comment: You probably don't want to force quit it because it forces you to rebackup your entire computer and you then loose the existing back up history

Comment: @Nate "… it will try to verify a ~750 GB disk image over Wi-Fi! …" – that's not what happens; only a *fraction* of the image is transmitted. Keyword: **CopyHFSMeta**, please see for example https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/time-machine-volume-keeps-corrupting.35247/page-2#post-259878

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been for days trying to figure out how to format my USB pendrive.

Answer (score 27):

Clicking on the Time Machine icon in the menu bar and choose "Skip verification" caused the `fsck_hfs` process to stop itself. Maybe a bit nicer than `kill`...

Comment: Just let it run, just wait for it finish.

Answer (score 3):

You can also click on the Time Machine icon, select "Open Time Machine Preferences...", and you should see a progress bar for how far along the "Backing Up" process is.

You can then click the "x" next to the progress bar to stop the verification process.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend against killing it.

Last time I did, it left my Time Machine backup in a state where OSX believed it to be corrupted. This resulted in OSX refusing to continue using this backup, i.e. OSX queried me to create a new backup (which would effectively mean I would loose any history in my backup, e.g. deleted files, previous versions of modified files, etc.)

I managed to bring the Time Machine backup into a good state, allowing OSX to continue using this backup, but it was quite a hassle.

Comment: Care to explain your process getting the backup back into a good state? I have an empty sparsebundle on my Time Machine now.

Comment: @MattM. If your sparsebundle is truly empty, I don't think you can save it. But if it's not empty, just marked as corrupt as mine was, it should be salvageable. I can't remember exactly what I did, found the solution through a google search. But the sparsebundle contains some metadata file that has a property telling that the backup is being checked/corrupt. So the process was something like unmount the time machine volume, find the metadata file, adjust those properties, and possibly remount the time machine volume (maybe I manually ran a verification step afterwards)

Comment: I used Data Rescue 4 for Mac, and it worked like a champ for $99. I didn't want to risk any irreversible loss by editing the metadata. It restored the data directly onto my local drive, reading the sparsebundle from Time Capsule connected over ethernet.